# Where can I ask a question about a laser engraver device?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

I'm having trouble with a laser engraver that I recently acquired. Most other places I've tried give me general advice on maintenance that I'm already aware of but don't help me solve the problem I have. I've come to Stack Exchange specifically because I feel I'm most likely to get a more expert opinion on my issue (unless there is a better place I can take my question to). I've tried Stack Exchange Engineering, but I was mistaken in going there and it turned out to be off topic. And I'm not familiar enough with this site to know where exactly to go.

The issue itself involves hardware and maintenance. I believe the problem stems from a piece that isn't working properly and that could have become the way it is due to a lack of maintenance that I was previously unaware of. There's a chance that the issue could also stem from the software used but I have my doubts.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you have? Hardware? Software? Care of? Installation and set up? Something else?

Comment: @RobertLongson Hardware and maintenance (or that's the best I can gather). There's a part that isn't working the way that it should and it makes certain images come out warped and I have reason to believe it's because of a lack of a specific form of maintenance that I'm unaware of and can't find anything about. There's the slight possibility it could be software related but I doubt that's it. The machine is already set up and has worked successfully for at least 30 hours since I put it together so I have less reason to believe it's an installation problem either.

Answer (score 4):

Despite the name, [3D Printing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/) seems to accept questions about laser engraving. (About this, [Robert Cartaino said](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/68) "it's not the 'name' that defines this site, but the intentions of the community that built it.")

For example, someone recently posted the question [laser is engraving the negative space](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/10010), which seems to be the same type of question that you would be asking.

Answer (score 2):

[3D Printing.SE](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) has a Tag for maintenance.